# How to configure the name returned from ping?

Tags: linux, networking, ping

Currently my Debian-based machine returns whatever name was used to ping it, as it's name when answering to ping:

```
 - saturn:~$ ifconfig | grep "inet addr"
          inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
 - saturn:~$ ping -c 1 192.168.0.103 | grep from
64 bytes from 192.168.0.103: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
 - saturn:~$ ping -c 1 localhost | grep from
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
 - saturn:~$ ping -c 1 saturn | grep from
64 bytes from saturn (127.0.1.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
 - saturn:~$
```

I would like to to always return "saturn". There is no DNS, this is on a local LAN with DHCP. I have read a question [regarding DNS](https://serverfault.com/questions/198377/can-you-control-the-host-information-returned-by-ping) but here there is no PTR record to configure. How can I have all pings return the name "saturn"?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please tell us what your final purpose is?

Comment: My final purpose is to know which machines I am communicating with if I address them by IP. If I want to know which machine is answering to 192.168.0.105 it would be nice if the ping returned "jupiter". Yes, there are eight machines!

Comment: Downvoters, please point out what is wrong with this question so that I might improve it. If you downvoted please leave a comment as to why. Thanks.

Comment: Setup a local DNS using [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) maybe is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a valid reason to want this?
This would be non-standard behaviour.

Ping (and other tools) looks up what the IP resolves to according to /etc/nsswitch.conf.
That's usually set to "files dns" for "hosts", meaning it will first look at /etc/hosts and then use DNS if that doesn't contain any useful info.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realise that this is nonstandard. Tell me, then, what determines what address is seen when pinging? For instance, when pinging `doorlinux.com` I see `shared02.exascale.co.uk`. Is there no way to configure that on a LAN with no DNS?

Comment: Well, without DNS, every machine would have to have some other way to resolve IPs to names. Most likely: `/etc/hosts` (*nix) or `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` (Windows). As to your example: try `host doorlinux.com` and then `host 178.239.170.13` (that's the output from the first execution of `host`). This should be enlightening? :)

Comment: I see. So when we ping doorlinux.com, the information `shared02.exascale.co.uk` is provided by DNS, and _not_ by the server answering the ping? And if there is no DNS, then that information is provided by the local Hosts file?

Comment: Quite so, yes. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For the local machine to return `saturn`, put this in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       saturn localhost
127.0.1.1       saturn localhost
192.168.0.103   saturn
```

**EDIT**

To use [`mDNS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) in linux, you need the [`avahi-daemon`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/avahi-daemon)...  I run this at home... this is what happens when I login to my debian server from my wife's ubuntu laptop which is also running `avahi-daemon`..

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ who
mpenning pts/0        2012-08-03 05:23 (jennykan-thinkpad-t61.local) <<<
mpenning pts/1        2012-08-02 01:16 (mpenning-vista.local)
[mpenning@tsunami ~]# ping jennykan-thinkpad-t61.local
PING jennykan-thinkpad-t61.local (172.16.1.74) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from jennykan-ThinkPad-T61.local (172.16.1.74): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.892 ms
64 bytes from jennykan-ThinkPad-T61.local (172.16.1.74): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=1.06 ms
^C
--- jennykan-thinkpad-t61.local ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.892/0.979/1.067/0.092 ms
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

This also assumes your network will pass multicast correctly... if you have a single Vlan, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Localhost should probably not resolve to an IP not on the loopback interface. (The loopback one should match first, of course, but then, even putting it on the 192.* line would be pointless.)

Comment: Thank you. My point isn't that when pinging oneself he should get "saturn" but rather that when another machine on the LAN pings 192.168.0.103 he should see "saturn".

Comment: Please see my edit